# how to integrrate capistrano recipes folder from capistrano legacy-v2 branch to master branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

On the above link if you select a branch legacy-v2   then in lib/capistrano folder there is **recipes** folder available.This folder is not in master branch so i clone this gem and tried to merge this but there are lots of conflict files as follows .

1. U    .travis.yml
2. U    Gemfile
3. U    README.md
4. U    Rakefile
5. U    bin/cap
6. U    bin/capify
7. U    capistrano.gemspec
8. U    lib/capistrano/configuration.rb
9. U    lib/capistrano/configuration/servers.rb
10. U   lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb
11. U   lib/capistrano/version.rb

    is there is any other way that in master branch i should have 
    this **recipes** folder integrated?

Comment: Why do you want this folder in the master branch?

Comment: because in that recipes folder they have code for perforce integration as scm that I want to integrate into my capistrano deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano 3 has changed its internal structure and recipes from capistrano 2 won't work. You need to use capistrano 2 to integrate with perforce.